# Make a diff between two tables

Tags: javascript

I have two tables in JavaScript and I have to make a function that will take two input arrays and make a diff and order. I want in the output :

- The different properties between tab1 and tab2
- Properties and more on tab1 tab2 over
- Properties and less on tab1 tab2 over

My table like [ key, value ]

```
var tab1= [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  data.push({
    key: i,
    value: "valeur"+i
  });
}
var tab2= [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 15; i++){
  data.push({
    key: i,
    value:"valeur"+i
  });
}
```

I do this but i don't have the good result:

```
for (var aa = 0; aa < tab1.length; aa++) {
                    var Find = false;
                    for (var bb = 0; bb < tab2.length; bb++) {
                        if (tab2[bb].name == $scope.properties.key_value_properties[aa].name) {
                            if (propertiesCible.key_value_properties[bb].value == tab1[aa].value) {
                                Find = true;
                                break;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    if (Find == false) {
                        finalTab.push({name:tab1[aa].name, valueRef: tab1[aa].value, valueCible: tab1[aa].value});
                    }
                    finalTabDiff.push({name: tab1[aa].name, valueRef: tab1[aa].value, valueCible: tab2[aa].value});

                }
```

Comment: please show how you made an effort to what you need.

Comment: @Daniel A. White sorry i have edit my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the lodash.js library.

Use _.keys() on the two objects to get two arrays of keys.
_.difference() will then reduce the two arrays of keys to a single array containing only the keys that are not in common.

Comment: ok i have the difference but how can i have the key and value in the final tab ?

Comment: Thank you giving me the answer. If you need any more help, please ask, I was at work on the problem right now.

Comment: For example I changed tab1 and tab2 into Objects rather than arrays, because _.keys() works on Objects. Then I actually first got the shared keys using _.intersection(keys1, keys2). Then I got the different keys using _.merge(_.difference(keys1, commonKeys), _.difference(keys2, commonKeys));